# Windows 2000 Terminal Server disconnecting users

Tags: terminal-server, windows-server-2000

My company has a Windows 2000 Terminal Server.

Every time 3 or more users connect to the server and run up some applications the server disconnects one of the users already connected to it?

The server is licensed for 10 users?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the settings on the Sessions tab of the RDP protocol on the server for any session limits that may be set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running it in administrative mode, which allows one console and two RDP sessions only. Check to ensure Terminal Services is in fact installed.

Comment: Hi

thank you for your reply - Terminal Services is installed and we can get 5 users all logged in but within a few minutes users are starting to get disconnected - I just have 5 users in but 2 have just been disconnected.

Comment: anything the 2 users getting disconnected have in common?  how are they different to the users not having problems?

Comment: the problem is its not just 2 users. it could 2, 3, 4 or all 5???

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the additional licenses in Terminal Services?

The standard Terminal Services only allow 5 connections without additional licenses loaded if I recall correctly.

The Microsoft documentation on how to do this is available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237811)

Comment: Yeah installed the cals - The server has now been fine for the last 1 hour and 30 minutes but has just started kicking users off it again!!!

Comment: It sounds more like an intermittent network problem. Have you seen any errors in the event log?

Comment: nothing in the terminal servers event logs

Comment: Out of interest what RDP client are you using to connect?

Comment: Remote Desktop Connection - Microsoft from Windows XP.

Comment: The latest 6.0 release or the older release?

Comment: Are users getting kicked off on thin clients or fat clients? If fat clients, can they still browse the web, etc., so you know it's not a network fault? Can the server reach the clients that are being disconnected, i.e., monitoring via a constant ping?

Comment: older release of RDP.